# 'Bde.DBTables.hpp' file not foundというエラーの解決方法

Tags: c++

Borland C++ Builder6で作成したプロジェクトファイルをC++ Builder 10.3の新規プロジェクトに一部ずつ加えてビルドできるかやっています。

プロジェクトにMain.cpp,Main.h,Main.dfmの3つのファイルを加えてビルドして、いくつかのエラーを回避していくうちに、次のようなエラーが発生しました。

> [bcc32c 致命的エラー] DBTables.hpp(11): 'Bde.DBTables.hpp' file not found

このようなエラーが出てきたのですが、回避方法などご教示頂きますよう、お願い致します。

Comment: 'Bde.DBTables.hpp' file not found
とエラーが表示されているのでファイルがないのではないかと思います。もしエラー内容のファイルが存在していたり参照してないということであれば、構成やソースコード、あなたの見解などを記載したほうが回答が付きやすいかと思います。

Answer (score 2):

Bde.DBTables.hppは、BDEというDBアクセス用コンポーネントのファイルですが、更新の停止と移行が推奨されてから結構経過し最近は標準でインストールされなくなっています。
製品版の場合は、後からBDEを追加することもできるようですがCommunity Editionで可能かは判りません。
公式のヘルプにBDEアプリケーションのFireDAC（現在のDBアクセス用コンポーネント）への移行方法がありますが、これもCommunity Editionで同じことが出来るかは不明です。
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/ja/BDE_%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E7%A7%BB%E8%A1%8C%EF%BC%88FireDAC%EF%BC%89

上記リンクの方法で移行できない場合は、簡単な回避方法は無いと思います。